# How could argument contravariance in Liskov principle work?

Tags: oop, liskov-substitution-principle

The basic point of Liskov substition principle is that a superclass can be replaced with a subclass which follows the same contract (behaviour). Or as Martin Fowler has put it: "Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it."

Argument contravariance is mentioned to be a part of LSP but I cannot seem to understand why and how it can work. I.e., in a subclass, the overriding method could accept wider (less derived argument).

something like this:

```
class Base
{
  int GetLenght(string s)
  {
     return s.lenght;
  }  
}
class Derived: Base
{
 override int GetLenght(object s)
  {
    ??  I cannot return any lenght of an object..
  }
}
```

How could this ever work? I mean, how could I comply with the contract if the less derived argument does not have the properties I need?

PS: I do know that most OO languages do not support that, I am just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets change the example a bit:

Let us for a moment assume that here is an interface `Sequence` which implements a `GetLength` method, and that `String` implements this interface.
Let us also assume that in your example, instead of object `Sequence` is used, which is a wider type then `String` (its actual implementation in this case).

```
Base base;
Derived derived;

String s;
Sequence o;

int i;
i = base.GetLength(s); // valid
i = derived.GetLength(o); // valid
i = base.GetLength(o); // obviously invalid

base = derived;
base.GetLength(s); // valid
base.getLength(o); // still invalid, 
// the contract of "Base" still requires an argument of type string,
// despite actually being of type "Derived"
```

You actual implementation is irrelevant, whats important is types. As long as you do not break the functionality when getting a string, you can return whatever floats your boat as length of arbitrary objects, for example:

```
class Derived : Base {
    override int GetLenght(Sequence s) {
      return s.GetLength();
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can can give `derived` *any* type of `Sequence`, but `Base` still requires the *specific* type of `String`.

Thus, contravariance works without violating the LSP in many cases. As you can see in your own example, you can not use `object` instead of `string` without arguably violating the LSP *in that regard* (You can and Base/Derived still don't violate the LSP, the LSP violation is hidden *inside* Derived, and not visible to the outside).

There are some really great articles by Eric Lippert about covariance and contravariance in C#, starting with 
[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/) (which goes up to Part 11).

More can be found here:
[Covariance and Contravariance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/page/3/)

As a side note:
While not violating he LSP is something to strife for, its not always the most economical choice. Working with 3rd party or legacy APIs, sometimes simply breaking the LSP can be a savior of sanity, time and resources.

Comment: I remember that any typecheck is precisely what violates LSp. As Fowler says, the code must not need to know/care. One of his articles explicitly says that

Comment: @user970696 Do you have any reference? It is the *public* APi that must not require type checks, whats done internally is up to the implementation and should be considered a black box - and in the example above, you don't need to type check anything when interacting with the public API of the class.

Comment: Im on the phone now but I am sure it is in the paper Fowler or Robert Martin wrote on rectangle/square problem. If your code usew type check, it means you obviously cannot simply replace the base class with the subclass. I will try to search and get back here

Comment: Quote: The LSP is violated, for example, whenever a client class has some logic dealing with the particular type of the implementation (such as Run Time Type Identification: if the actual type is this, then do that, otherwise do that other thing - or something along this line)

Comment: @user970696 In the example shown above, the client (the caller) does not have to do such checks, so there is no such violation.

Comment: I think I found that: http://www.labri.fr/perso/clement/enseignements/ao/LSP.pdf. Check page 2, it is very short

Comment: @user970696 Yes, thats what I am always talking about. In the example given, the *caller* has to make the judgement, the LSP is violated. In the example that I have shown, it is not. You can use the public API of both `Base` and `Derived` without any inspection of the type. The mere presence of introspection of the type doesn't necessarily mean a violation of the LSP. The only thing you *could* argue was that object violates the LSP when used in place of String, but thats about object/string, not Base/Derived.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it. Just curious, why would object violate LSP if that is a base class of string?

Comment: Because as you can see, you can not use `object` and expect it to behave the same as `string`. Thats why I said that you could argue that there is an LSP violation with object/string in that example, but your question was about contravariance. Replace object/string in your example with an interface and its actual implementation and there is no LSP violation in that regard anymore, and contravariance works.

Comment: @user970696 I have changed the example code to make it more clear where the LSP occurs and where not.

Answer (score 3):

> Argument contravariance is mentioned to be a part of LSP but I cannot seem to understand why and how it can work. I.e., in a subclass, the overriding method could accept wider (less derived argument).

First of all let's make sure we have defined our terms.

"Covariance" is a property of *relations and transformations*. Specifically it is the property that *a particular relation is maintained over a particular transformation*.  "Contravariance" is the same as covariance except that it is that a particular relation is *maintained but reversed* over a transformation.

Let's give an example. I have a type in hand and I wish to transform it into a different type by the rule `T` is transformed to `Func<T>`.  I have a relation between types: "an expression of type `X` can be assigned to a variable of type `Y`"  For example, an expression of type `Giraffe` can be assigned to a variable of type `Animal`.  The transformation is *covariant* because the relation is preserved across the transformation: an expression of type `Func<Giraffe>` can be assigned to a variable of type `Func<Animal>`.

The transformation `T` is transformed to `Action<T>` reverses the relation: `Action<Animal>` can be assigned to `Action<Giraffe>`.

But the `T` in `Action<T>` is the formal parameter type of the method represented by the delegate.  So as you see, we can have contravariance on formal parameter types.

What does this mean for method overriding?  When you say

```
class B 
{
  public virtual void M(Giraffe g) { b body }
}
class D : B 
{
  public override void M(Giraffe g) { d body }
}
```

That is logically the same as

```
class B 
{
  protected Action<Giraffe> a = g => { b body }; 
  public void M(Giraffe g) { this.a(g); }
}
class D : B 
{
  public D() {  
    this.a = g => { d body };
  }
}
```

Right? It would be perfectly legal for us to replace D's constructor with

```
   this.a = some Action<Animal>
```

right? However, C# -- and most other OO languages, but not all -- do not allow

```
class D : B 
{
  public override void M(Animal a) { d body }
}
```

even though *logically* it works just as well as generic delegate contravariance works. It's just a feature that could be implemented that never is implemented because there are so many better things to do.

> How could this ever work? I mean, how could I comply with the contract if the less derived argument does not have the properties I need?

Well if you couldn't, then you wouldn't, would you?

Suppose I need

```
int CompareHeights(Giraffe g1, Giraffe g2)
```

Does it seem so implausible that I could replace this with a method

```
int CompareHeights(Animal a1, Animal a2)
```

? I need a method that compares heights of giraffes, I have a method that compares heights of animals, so I'm done, right?

Suppose I need

```
void Paint(Circle, Color)
```

Does it seem implausible that I could replace this with a method

```
void Paint(Shape, Color)
```

? That seems plausible to me. I need a method that paints circles, I have a method that paints any shape, so I am done.

If I need

```
int GetLength(string)
```

and I have

```
int GetLength(IEnumerable)
```

then I'm good. I need a method that gets the length of a string, which is a sequence of chars. I have a method that can get the length of any sequence, so I'm good.

Comment: Eric, I think it would work with simple delegates as well. Declaring a delegate requiring Giraffe, I could (in the derived class) assign to it a method requiring Animal.

Answer (score 0):

This could work because consumers of the base class call it using the interface of the base class (they don't need to know about the derived class), and since the subclass is less restrictive, any argument that could be passed to the base class method can be passed to the subclass method. 
(In your example, a consumer of `Base` would pass a `string` to `Base.GetLenght` (and it couldn't pass any other type because it's reference is to the method with the `string` parameter), which is overridden by `Derived.GetLenght`, and  `Derived.GetLenght` would receive the `string` argument, which is valid for it).

Consumers of the subclass can have a reference typed as the type of the subclass (i.e. they are aware of its less restrictive interface) and so can pass any argument accepted by the subclass. This argument is passed to the subclass method (which can accept that argument). Of course, if the overriding method was to call the base class method, it would have to convert (or substitute) the argument to something that is valid for the base class.

Of course, the overriding method has to be able to handle its argument. In the example, that means that it has to have a way of getting the 'length' of any object, and must define what that actually means.

**Semantics**

A well-written base class would define the contract of what the method should do (in a comment, for example).
Conforming to the Liskov Substitution Principle in the derived class also requires semantically conforming to that (at least not contradicting it), so that it doesn't return unexpected (but *syntactically* valid) values for a consumer of the base class.

In the example, this would probably mean (depending on the semantic contract of that method) that if the argument was a `string`, the overriding method must return the length (requiring checking its type and casting it).

For example, the base class method might have a comment stating: `returns the number of characters in the string and returns -1 if 's' is null.`

The overriding method might have a comment that says `Given any sequence or collection (including a string, which is treated as a sequence of characters for this purpose), this returns the number of elements in the sequence or collection, and returns -1 if the argument is null or not a collection or sequence.` 
Note that by this definition, it does the same thing as the base class when passed a string. If it did not (for example, by returning 0 or throwing an exception when passed null), *that* would be a Liskov violation, even if its parameter type was the same.

Then it would have to implement that by checking the type of the argument, and casting to the appropriate type to get the size of the collection or length of the string (it could cast and call the base class for the latter).

**Possible Implementation**

In most object-oriented languages, When the parameter type of both methods is an object (usually implemented by a piece of data that starts with a reference to type information),
the entry in the virtual method table for `Derived.GetLenght` could be the same as if it had the same parameter type (i.e. directly pointing to that method), with the type checking done at compile time.

If one of the methods had a parameter that was not binary compatible with the other (for example if the base class took and int (for which the compiler passed just a 32-bit value) and the derived class took an object), the overriding method (in the source code) would be compiled as a new method (with its own entry in the virtual method table), and the compiler could internally generate a method with the prototype of the base class method, that casts the argument and passes it to the overriding method. (The latter is what the virtual method table entry would point to in the derived class.)

If the method were overridden again in a class derived from the derived class, this mechanism could also be used, but the compiler would have to internally generate these overriding methods for all superclass methods (including the top level one), casting and calling the overridden method in this lowest class.

Comment: Hmm but how can you get the lenght of the string if you pass the object now? I

Comment: @JohnV The contract of the overriding method specifies what is meant by the 'length' of its argument. If the parameter is a string, it must return a value consistent with the contract of the base class (the length), so it would probably check the type of its argument, and return the string length (probably by calling the base class) if it is a string,